# Tree table in jquery with multi level children

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to implement this tree table

My json structure is :

```
var jsonFormat = [{"father": {"id": "A","name": "AE","adr": "ME11","bloc": bac,"etat": "W"},"children": [{"id": "18694","name": "AE","adr": "ME11","bloc": bac,"etat": "C","level_data": "2"},{"id": "18694","name": "AE","adr": "ME11","bloc": bac,"level_data": "2"},{"id": "18694","name": "AE","adr": "ME11","bloc": bac,"level_data": "2"}]},{"father": {"id": "A","name": "AE","adr": "ME11","bloc": bac,"etat": "W"},"children": [{"message": "No parent","level_data": "2"}]}]
```

And i want to create a tree table and if the children of parent have no data, i create a rowspan and write it No data .

Anyone can i help me ?

[image: treetable]

Comment: check url: https://datatables.net/ might be helpful.

Comment: @Prassad Wagrad very thanks but your datatable example doesn't do exactly what i want.. Because this example show One step of child

Comment: Have a look at the url: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50218/table-inside-a-childrow-of-another-table which gives a working example fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/sawapoci/1/edit . That example shows table inside table, in that example child table too made as datatable which you can skip & keep that as a normal table by just commenting code lines $('#child_details').DataTable({ destroy: true, scrollY: '100px' });

Comment: Hello @PrasadWargad , I do this example link http://live.datatables.net/hecedicu/1/edit    but i have a problem, my datatable doesn't display parent and children. The key word for parent or children is level_data. When leve_data is 0 that's father if the level data is 1 or more is the children. And when the children has no data , i want to write in my table no data for this children